# Parsing JSON data with Jquery to set a background image

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm working with another developer's code, which the client has asked me to upgrade.
What I need to do is to use Jquery to retrieve the generated contents of a PHP file and parse them so that I can use the elements from the file in the page. The generated contents are in JSON format, like this:

```
    {
    "productid": "3621",
    "id": "24",
    "title": "Oak+Veneer+26mm",
    "description": "Oak+Veneer%2C+26mm+width%2C+21mm+deep%2C+14mm+rebate",
    "mouldingimage": "L1545a.jpg",
    "frameimagetop": "L1545_top.jpg",
    "frameimagebottom": "L1545_bottom.jpg",
    "frameimagevertical": "L1545_vert.jpg",
    "unitprice": "0.18",
    "banda": {},
    "bandb": {},
    "bandc": {},
    "bandd": {},
    "bande": {},
    "notes": {},
    "code": "L1545",
    "deliveryperiodid": "107",
    "deliverybandid": "64",
    "supplierid": "115",
    "date": "2011-10-07+16%3A27%3A32",
    "active": "0",
    "previousunitprice": {}
}
```

I need to get the value of 'frameimagetop' from the data above, then use that to set the background image of a div.

I've tried doing variations of the following, but I can't get it to work:

```
$.getJSON('/getframedata.php', {
    id: $(this).attr("id")
}, {
    get_param: 'frameimagetop'
}, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
        $('#frame_top').append($('<div>', {
            text: element.name
        }));
```

I know the above won't set the background image of the div, but at the moment, I can't even get it to print out the text.

Comment: I formatted your code block so you could see the obvious structure deficiencies therein, the JSON block seems OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('/getframedata.php', function(data) {
    var bgImage = data.frameimagetop;
    <code...>
});
```

More details available at the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
Like success/failure handlers, etc...

Comment: I'll add that it's better not to rely on jQuery guessing and output json content type: header('Content-Type: application/json')

Comment: Thanks @msplay, with your advice I worked out this solution:
$.getJSON('/getframedata.php', {id: $(this).attr("id")}, function(data) {
   var bgImage = data.frameimagetop;
   $('#frame_top').css('background-image', 'url(/data/customframes/' + bgImage + ')');
  });
Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

JSON you provided is an object. It means that you shouldn't iterate through it (you use $.each) to get some exact value. I.e. if you need "frameimagetop" property you can do it like that: `object.property_name`. In your example it would be:

```
$.getJSON('/getframedata.php', 
    { id: $(this).attr("id") },
    function(data) { 
       alert(data.frameimagetop);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

getJSON is shortcut for:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

Most use a success handler, so:

```
$.getJSON('/getframedata.php', {
    id: $(this).attr("id")
}, function (data) {
    $('#frame_top').css("background-image", "url(" + data.frameimagetop + ")");
});
```